# NSTimer calls the selector method twice on the same thread?

Tags: ios, nstimer

1) I created a NSTimer on viewdidload

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    NSLog(@"************In viewDidLoad method initializng timer [%@]",[NSThread currentThread]);
#endif
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(onTimerKicks:) userInfo:clues repeats:YES];
```

2) The selector call back performs some conditional logic (Play back time of a video) . The problem is every time the timer wakes up it calls the selector method *twice* for the same instance on the same thread !!! How do I know ? NS log statements printing thread details and debug.

```
- (void) onTimerKicks:(NSTimer *) timer
{

    if (currentPlaybackTime == 10) {

#ifndef NDEBUG
        NSLog(@"[%@] ************calling onTimerKicks:onAutoPageTimer from onTimer current playbacktime = %d", [NSThread currentThread], currentPlaybackTime);
#endif

    }
}
```

3) Here is the debug for one wake up of the timer

```
2011-08-30 19:11:51.759 MASLTales[7735:207] ************In viewDidLoad method initializng timer [<NSThread: 0x580f3a0>{name = (null), num = 1}]
2011-08-30 19:12:05.760 MASLTales[7735:207] [<NSThread: 0x580f3a0>{name = (null), num = 1}] ************ccalling onTimerKicks:onAutoPageTimer from onTimer current playbacktime = 10
2011-08-30 19:12:06.260 MASLTales[7735:207] [<NSThread: 0x580f3a0>{name = (null), num = 1}] ************ccalling onTimerKicks:onAutoPageTimer from onTimer current playbacktime = 10
```

Anybody knows why I see this message twice all the time ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not calling the selector twice, it is calling selector continously because while initializing timer you have written `repeats:YES];.` But in your selector there is a conditional block which is true only for a 1 sec and your timer is firing selector for every half second. So its printing twice.

Comment: Vow that was quick. I increased my timer to for for every 2 seconds. Now it all makes sense. Thanks a lot 'saadnib'